# when try to remove an object from array in mongodb acknowledged: true, modifiedCount: 0, upsertedId: null, upsertedCount: 0, matchedCount: 1

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, crud

I have faced some issue while try to removed  an nested object from a mongodb. It returns:

```
acknowledged: true,
  modifiedCount: 0,
  upsertedId: null,
  upsertedCount: 0,
  matchedCount: 1
```

Here is structure of data in mongo db, and I try to removed on of those reviews from the reviews array

```
{
        "_id": "63694065ba91a2efff807e48",
        "title": "Data Science",
        "img": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AriyanShihab/ass10server/main/assi-11/dataScince.webp",
        "description": "Data science is the study of data to extract meaningful insights for business. It is a multidisciplinary approach that combines principles and practices from the fields of mathematics, statistics, artificial intelligence, and computer engineering to analyze large amounts of data.",
        "price": 2300,
        "ratings": 9.4,
        "students": 6267,
        "createdAt": 1667841824476,
        "reviews": [
            {
                "user": "Ariyan Shihab",
                "userImage": "https://ariyanshihab.github.io/repoLibrary/images/profile.png",
                "reviews": "Data Science review -01\n ",
                "email": "devshihab111@gmail.com",
                "insertTime": 1667902675223,
                "id": "636a2cd30d784ce49fe1f5c9"
            },
            {
                "user": "Ariyan Shihab",
                "userImage": "https://ariyanshihab.github.io/repoLibrary/images/profile.png",
                "reviews": "Data Science review -02\n ",
                "email": "devshihab111@gmail.com",
                "insertTime": 1667902684206,
                "id": "636a2cdc0d784ce49fe1f5ca"
            },
            {
                "user": "Ariyan Shihab",
                "userImage": "https://ariyanshihab.github.io/repoLibrary/images/profile.png",
                "reviews": "Data Science review - 05",
                "email": "devshihab111@gmail.com",
                "insertTime": 1667909790286,
                "id": "636a489ffa9f43310defb1f9"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Here is my query in my express server

```
app.delete("/del-review", async (req, res) => {
      // reviewID--- i have passed it from front-end and req.body
      // that is the intire review object
      const { reviewID } = req.body;

      const deleteReviews = await serviseCollection.updateOne(
        {},
        {
          $pull: {
            reviews: { $elemMatch: { id: reviewID.id, email: reviewID.email } },
          },
        }
      );
      console.log(deleteReviews);

      res.send({ grettings: "Hello world" });
    });
```

Note: I'm just started learning mongodb a few days ago, if anyone can help me solve this, I would be grateful.

I'm expecting to removed a specific object from the nested collection in mongodb

Comment: Do you intend to update a specific document? Right now your `updateOne` specifies no matching conditions (`{}`). This means that _all_ documents will match. So the database is selecting the first document as the target for the operation (`matchedCount: 1`) but determining that there is no matching entry in the array to `$pull` hence not modifying the document (`modifiedCount: 0`).  Perhaps the `updateOne` should specify the `_id` of a document to target or otherwise include a check to make sure the target document includes the entry in the array to remove.

Comment: @user20042973 thank you for your concern. unfortunately, the result is the same even after adding a query in the first params  const deleteReviews = await serviseCollection.updateOne(
        {
          _id: ObjectId(parentObjectId),
        },
        {
          $pull: {
            reviews: { $elemMatch: { id: reviewID.id, email: reviewID.email } },
          },
        }
      );

Comment: What are the contents of the document that matches `{ _id: ObjectId(parentObjectId), }`? Without information like that we can only guess at what might be happening